# Restore SQL Server database I accidently replaced?

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I restored a SQL server database from a backup file, but I accidentally replaced a database I needed and override it.

Is there a way to somehow get it back?

I know the answer will probably be no, but thought I should ask anyway.

In using SQL Server 2014

Comment: I think there is a reason you have to manually check the box to overwrite a database...

Comment: I would check your SQL Server data directory to see if the .mdb files are still there, but if you used the `WITH REPLACE` option and used the same file names as the database you accidentally restored to, then your database is lost.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to recover from backups. Worth checking with your server admin to see if they are doing anything like drive snapshots/backups to see if you can recover it another way.